# Best way to store key/value domain parameters in Spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have some custom domain variables such as exchange rates, conversion values and so on with different data types like String, BigDecimal, Integer and so on..

Is there a simple way to store and retrieve this kind of values associated to a String key using Spring Data? Or should I write my own Repository to handle this functionality?

Comment: http://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-redis-tutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The project page of Spring Data](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data/) lists the various modules in existence. Among those is [Spring Data Redis](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-redis/) and [Spring Data Hazelcast](https://github.com/hazelcast/spring-data-hazelcast), which provide abstractions over a key value store.

If you want to build your own module, [Spring Data Key Value](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-keyvalue) might be a good basis.